# How to make the OS think a removable media drive is non-removable?

Tags: terminal, usb, storage

I'd like to be able to use a USB pen drive as if it's an internal drive - is this possible?

I saw some info about flipping the 'removable flag bit' of the drive using terminal command

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/disk2 bs=1 count=1
```

however, after trying with a number of 64 GB pen drives from different manufacturer I always get the message

```
Operation not permitted
```

I tried SUDO before the command (eek) but no difference.

Any other ways to do this, or perspectives to add?